# How to create map<string, class::method> in c++

Tags: c++, callback

I'm trying to use callback to create a map of string and method in C++, so i can search a funtion in a map and call it.  I did it in the following way. The problem is  i have methods with different types and parameters and i don't know how to define the callback and map. The method works fine for int add(int, int) and int subtract(int, int), but how to define callback for method string helloworld()?
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
typedef int(*Callback)(int, int); //for add and subtract
QMap<QString, Callback> functionTable;

main{

    registerCallback("add", add);
    registerCallback("subtract", subtract);

    int result = 0;
    if (functionTable.contains(add))
    {
        Callback callback = functionTable[add];
        result = callback(1, 2);
        return QString::number(result) ;

    }
    else
    {
        return "methodNotFound";
    }

}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int subtract(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

String helloWorld()
{
    return "hello world";
}
void registerCallback(QString methodname, Callback callback)
{
    functionTable[methodname] = callback;
}
```

Comment: The pattern you're looking for is called the _delegate pattern_. There are many available implementations and tutorials on this matter. Try this one for example: http://blog.molecular-matters.com/2011/09/19/generic-type-safe-delegates-and-events-in-c/

Comment: Thanks i will take a look@Paweł Stawarz

Comment: You cannot place functions with different signatures in the same map. Why are you trying to?

Comment: i'm trying to implement jsonrpc call which calls different methods with different parameters in the server. @ n.m.

Comment: jsonrpc doesn't have a concept of different function signatures. Every jsonrpc function accepts a single array of strings as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports C++11 standard (it almost certainly does) you can use `std::function` from `<functional>` header. Since this modern C++ feature is extensively used in last MS Office releases (according to MSVC++ Dev blog), this should work pretty smoothly. In the GNU C++ compiler it adds two CPU instructions to each call.

Comment: If it does not `boost::function` can be used instead

Comment: @Slava: It's almost five years since C++11. Throw away your mammonth's shit and obtain a decent compiler already.

Comment: And absence of such a useful feature in the C++98 was a truly epic failure.

Comment: I do have decent compiler, I just added to your answer "if your compiler supports". And not everybody can choose which compiler to use.